# Transpose specific rows into columns using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file

So I have a CSV file with rows that I want to transpose (some of them) into columns using PowerShell.

The example is as follows:

```
ALPHA
CD
CL
CM
-5
0.1
-0.2
0.05
0
0.4
0.4
-0.08
5
0.5
0.8
-0.1
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Alpha  CD    CL    CM
-5     0.1  -0.2   0.05
 0     0.4   0.4  -0.08
 5     0.5   0.8  -0.1
```

For reference I got these values from a `.dat` data file output with over 400 rows full of information. I reformatted it into a CSV file using `out-file`, and I skipped all the rows I don't need.
The information was split into rows but not columns, meaning `ALPHA CD CL CM` were all in one cell with spaces in between, so I used the `split` command as shown below to break them into rows.

```
$ text .split () | where { $ _ }
```

Now I want to transpose SOME of them back into columns.

The problem is it's not fixed amounts, meaning it's not always four rows into four columns, sometimes I would get five rows that I want to turn into five columns, and THEN turn every four rows into four columns AFTER that.

Sorry if I'm rambling but it's something like this:

```
Row 1 > Column 1 Row 1
Row 2 > Column 2 Row 1
Row 3 > Column 3 Row 1
Row 4 > Column 4 Row 1
Row 5 > Column 5 Row 1
Row 6 > Column 1 Row 2
Row 7 > Column 2 Row 2
Row 8 > Column 3 Row 2
Row 9 > Column 4 Row 2
Row 10 > Column 5 Row 2
Row 11 > Column 1 Row 3
Row 12 > Column 2 Row 3
Row 13 > Column 3 Row 3
Row 14 > Column 4 Row 3
Row 15 > Column 1 Row 4
```

Please notice how it went from five columns to four columns now.

If it can be done easier in other methods other than PowerShell where I can use PowerShell to run them, i.e. a batch file that calls PowerShell, that would be good by me as I need to automate a very long process, and this is one of the later process steps.

PS: The data are NOT comma separated cleanly. The used program *DATCOM* outputs a data file where it looks neat and structured in text format, but when you export CSV it destroys it, so it has to be done using:

```
out-file name csv
```

PPS: There is no clear delimiter/cutoff point, and there are no repeating numbers or anything else that can be used as a hint. I have to do it by row number, which I know due to dealing with *DATCOM* before.

I explained more above, but I tried using `split` commands. It dropped them all into rows. So if there is a way that can just do a literal text to columns delimit using spaces (exactly like in *Excel*) that would be perfect, and even better than breaking them into rows then transposing to columns. However, it has to be EXACTLY like *Excel*. The problem is there are 4-8 "spaces" between each value, so if I try to

```
import-csv -delim " "
```

on the file I get something like `Alpha H1 H2 H3 CD H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 CL` and everything else gets destroyed, whereas if I actually open *Excel*, highlight cells, text to columns > delimited > check "spaces" the results are perfect.

Here are the files: https://easyupload.io/m/6q70ei

- `for006.dat` is the data file generated by *DATCOM*.
- `Output1` is what I want done as described above (row to column).
- `Output2` is what I hope I can do later, i.e. delete a column and a row to make it cleaner, this is my ideal final output.

Comment: Have you still got the original file? It might be easier to extract just the data you need form there instead of working on the one-column version.

Comment: I have all the files, the problem is this DATCOM software outputs as I said 400+ rows of information, and I only need 20 rows and 6 columns, for this problem. Manually it's easily done, but when you have to run hundreds of cases, automation is the best method. If you have a method that can extract said information from the original .dat file, I'd be more than happy to share it with you.

Comment: @vonPryz I didn't know how to mention, so I had to write another comment, sorry, but yes I have all the original files, and if having a .dat file with no clear delimiter is better than what I turned it into, please advise me on how to proceed with it, I can also provide the original .dat file if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... I am afraid your description is pretty confusing, so I forgot it and focused in your files...

The Batch file below read the `for006.dat` file and generate your "ideal final output" `Output2.xlsx` file in .csv form.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "skip="
set "lines="
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /L /C:" ALPHA" for006.dat') do (
   if not defined skip (
      set /A "skip=%%a-1"
   ) else if not defined lines (
      set /A "lines=%%a-skip-1"
   )
)

< for006.dat (
   for /L %%a in (1,1,%skip%) do set /P "="
   for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do (
      set /P "line="
      set "line=!line:~2!"
      if defined line call :reformat
   )
) > Output2.csv
goto :EOF

:reformat
   set "newLine=%line:  = %"
   if "%newLine%" == "%line%" goto continue
   set "line=%newLine%"
goto reformat

:continue
if "%line:~0,1%" == " " set "line=%line:~1%"
if "%line:~-1%" == " " set "line=%line:~0,-1%"
echo "%line: =","%"
```

This is Output2.csv:

```
"ALPHA","CD","CL","CM","CN","CA","XCP","CLA","CMA","CYB","CNB","CLB"
"-6.0","0.013","-0.175","0.2807","-0.176","-0.006","-1.599","3.100E+00","-3.580E+00","-5.643E-02","-3.080E-03","-8.679E-02"
"-3.0","0.011","-0.011","0.0926","-0.012","0.010","-7.977","3.172E+00","-3.626E+00","-8.989E-02"
"0.0","0.013","0.157","-0.0990","0.157","0.013","-0.631","3.286E+00","-3.740E+00","-9.305E-02"
"3.0","0.019","0.333","-0.2991","0.334","0.001","-0.897","3.426E+00","-3.901E+00","-9.635E-02"
"6.0","0.029","0.516","-0.5075","0.516","-0.025","-0.984","3.529E+00","-4.084E+00","-9.979E-02"
"7.5","0.036","0.609","-0.6158","0.608","-0.044","-1.013","3.472E+00","-4.002E+00","-1.015E-01"
"9.0","0.043","0.698","-0.7171","0.696","-0.067","-1.031","3.218E+00","-3.679E+00","-1.032E-01"
"10.0","0.047","0.752","-0.7791","0.748","-0.084","-1.041","2.895E+00","-3.489E+00","-1.042E-01"
"11.0","0.051","0.799","-0.8388","0.794","-0.102","-1.057","2.572E+00","-3.345E+00","-1.051E-01"
"12.0","0.055","0.841","-0.8958","0.835","-0.121","-1.073","2.320E+00","-3.178E+00","-1.059E-01"
"13.0","0.059","0.880","-0.9498","0.870","-0.140","-1.091","2.041E+00","-2.983E+00","-1.066E-01"
"14.0","0.063","0.913","-0.9999","0.901","-0.160","-1.110","1.738E+00","-2.772E+00","-1.072E-01"
"15.0","0.066","0.940","-1.0465","0.925","-0.180","-1.131","1.356E+00","-2.567E+00","-1.077E-01"
"16.0","0.067","0.960","NA","0.941","-0.201","NA","1.798E-02","NA","-1.081E-01"
"18.0","0.055","0.883","NA","0.857","-0.220","NA","-4.434E+00","NA","-1.066E-01"
```

You can also generate the .csv output file with no quotes by just removing the quotes from the last `echo` command

Comment: oh my god are you a legend!
Thx a lot man, this works perfectly!

Comment: In such a case you should select my solution as "Best Answer" (click on the green check-mark) and upvote it...

Comment: So? Couldn't perform a simple couple of clicks?  *`;)`*

Comment: Sorry, I never used StackOverflow before, I clicked on Upvote, and it said I need more rep to do so, so I thought best answer would be chosen automatically.
Edit: Oh, and I didn't check this response in 2 weeks as I have been pretty busy, so didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell's Begin/Process/End lifecycle to "buffer" input data until you have enough for a "row", then output that and start collecting for the next row:

```
# define width of each row as well as the column separator
$columnCount = 5
$delimiter = "`t"

# read in the file contents, "cell-by-cell"
$rawCSVData = Get-Content path\to\input\file.txt |ForEach-Object -Begin {
    # set up a buffer to hold 1 row at a time
    $index = 0
    $buffer = [psobject[]]::new($columnCount)
} -Process  {
    # add input to buffer, and optionally output
    $buffer[$index++] = $_
    if($index -eq $columnCount){
        # output row, reset column index
        $buffer -join $delimiter
        $index = 0
    }
} -End {
    # Output any partial last row
    if($index){
        $buffer -join $delimiter
    }
}
```

This will produce a list of strings that can either be written to disk or parsed using regular CSV-parsing tools in PowerShell:

```
$rawCSVData |Set-Content path\to\output.csv
# or
$rawCSVData |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I get the following error from executing your code: 

~~~
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:12 char:5
+     $buffer[$index++] = $_
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException
~~~

Comment: @Nawaf_Ar sorry, I typo'd `$index` as `$idx` twice, hence the error. It's fixed now, give it another go :)

Comment: Hi @mathias-r-jessen
Thx for the quick response it worked perfectly for the text I provided in the question, however if it's not too much trouble can you check the files I added? The problem here is some columns only having ONE row under them, and no other data. Namely columns 11 and 12 only have 1 row.
Or if possible since I only need columns 1:4, is there a way for me to skip specific rows? 
I only know of Select-Object -skip and -skiplast, not sure if there's a skip (insert the row number you want skipped) if that's possible, I can do it, and use your code
Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$columns = 4
$data = 
"@ALPHA
CD
CL
CM
-5
0.1
-0.2
0.05
0
0.4
0.4
-0.08
5
0.5
0.8
-0.1@"
$data | Format-Table
$headers = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$rows = [System.IO.StringReader]::new($data)
for($i = 0; $i -lt $columns; $i++)
{
   $headers.Add($rows.ReadLine())
}
$rowCount = 0
Write-Host $headers
While(($line = $rows.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   if($rowCount % $columns -eq 0)
   {
       $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
       $table.Add($newRow)
   }
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $headers[$rowCount % $columns] -NotePropertyValue $line
   $rowCount++
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you know how many rows form the headers and the data, you can convert the file into
an array of objects by using `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

When done, it is easy to create a new csv from this as below:

```
# in this example the first 4 lines are the columns, the rest is data
# other files may need a different number of columns
$columns = 4  
$data    = @(Get-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\data.txt')
$count   = 0
$result = while ($count -lt ($data.Count - ($columns - 1))) {
    $data[$count..($count + $columns - 1)] -join "`t"  # join the lines with a TAB
    $count += $columns
}

$result = $result | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to new csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\data_new.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
ALPHA CD  CL   CM   
----- --  --   --   
-5    0.1 -0.2 0.05 
0     0.4 0.4  -0.08
5     0.5 0.8  -0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two (custom) functions that might help you to scrape your data from the `for006.dat`:

- SelectString -From -To (see: [`#15136` Add `-From` and `-To` parameters to `Select-String`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136))
- [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)

```
Get-Content .\for006.dat |
SelectString -From '(?=0 ALPHA     CD       CL.*)' -To '^0.+' |
ForEach-Object { $_.SubString(1) } |
ConvertFrom-SourceTable |
ConvertTo-Csv
```

Results:

```
"ALPHA","CD","CL","CM","CN","CA","XCP","CLA","CMA","CYB","CNB","CLB"
"-6","0.013","-0.175","0.2807","-0.176","-0.006","-1.599","3.100E+00","-3.580E+00","-5.643E-02","-3.080E-03","-8.679E-02"
"-3","0.011","-0.011","0.0926","-0.012","0.01","-7.977","3.172E+00","-3.626E+00","","","-8.989E-02"
"0","0.013","0.157","-0.0990","0.157","0.013","-0.631","3.286E+00","-3.740E+00","","","-9.305E-02"
"3","0.019","0.333","-0.2991","0.334","0.001","-0.897","3.426E+00","-3.901E+00","","","-9.635E-02"
"6","0.029","0.516","-0.5075","0.516","-0.025","-0.984","3.529E+00","-4.084E+00","","","-9.979E-02"
"7.5","0.036","0.609","-0.6158","0.608","-0.044","-1.013","3.472E+00","-4.002E+00","","","-1.015E-01"
"9","0.043","0.698","-0.7171","0.696","-0.067","-1.031","3.218E+00","-3.679E+00","","","-1.032E-01"
"10","0.047","0.752","-0.7791","0.748","-0.084","-1.041","2.895E+00","-3.489E+00","","","-1.042E-01"
"11","0.051","0.799","-0.8388","0.794","-0.102","-1.057","2.572E+00","-3.345E+00","","","-1.051E-01"
"12","0.055","0.841","-0.8958","0.835","-0.121","-1.073","2.320E+00","-3.178E+00","","","-1.059E-01"
"13","0.059","0.88","-0.9498","0.87","-0.140","-1.091","2.041E+00","-2.983E+00","","","-1.066E-01"
"14","0.063","0.913","-0.9999","0.901","-0.160","-1.110","1.738E+00","-2.772E+00","","","-1.072E-01"
"15","0.066","0.94","-1.0465","0.925","-0.180","-1.131","1.356E+00","-2.567E+00","","","-1.077E-01"
"16","0.067","0.96","NA","0.941","-0.201","NA","1.798E-02","NA","","","-1.081E-01"
"18","0.055","0.883","NA","0.857","-0.220","NA","-4.434E+00","NA","","","-1.066E-01"
```